# How do I go about configuring Poliigon textures to be compatible with glTF export?

Tags: texturing, gltf

I have already referenced/followed the gltf export docs located here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html

Instead of using node wrangler or equiv, it seems like I need to manually assemble the nodes/shaders in order to get the textures to export in the GLTF format properly.

The listed GLTF compatible "materials" are:

- Base Color
- Metallic
- Roughness
- Baked Ambient Occlusion
- Normal Map
- Emissive

My goal is to use a poliigon texture but the channels are very different from the ones listed above. See below:

- AO
- BUMP
- COL_VAR
- DISP
- GLOSS
- IDMAP
- NRM
- REFL

My ask:

1. Is is possible to use poliigon textures with glb/gltf files?
2. If so, how do I take the poliigon texture channels and convert them to a "metal/rough PBR texture" that is compatible with the gltf exporter?

I cannot provide a file for this particular example because the texture is paid for, however here is the link to purchase/review: https://www.poliigon.com/texture/concrete-blocks-painted-cinder-001/5362

Poliigon's free textures have the exact same formats for reference.

I have searched far and wide for a solution but I cannot find one. I am happy to answer or clarify my questions if they are not understood.

thanks!

Comment: Poliigon textures aren't some special textures. They are images, just like the rest of them. Although in this case you did need to tell us what were the different maps that were available, them being poliigon textures don't make them any different than the maps which are found elsewhere.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 0):

Poliigon textures:

- AO = Ambient Occlusion Map. Supported.
- BUMP = Bump Map. Not supported; use Normal Map instead.
- COL_VAR = Base Color Map, I think? Supported.
- DISP = Displacement Map. Not supported.
- GLOSS = Glossiness Map. Invert the colors and it becomes a Roughness Map.
- IDMAP = ???
- NRM = Normal Map. Supported.
- REFL = ???

Of those listed above, you can export AO, Base Color, Glossiness (with conversion to Roughness), and Normal Maps. See the glTF exporter documentation for how to connect them to a Principled BSDF material. Perhaps also Reflectivity, but Poliigon would need to provide a technical explanation of what the data is and how it could be converted to, for example, a Specular Map.

glTF supports considerably more textures than those listed in your post, which are only described as the "core material system" in the Blender documentation. Scroll further down and you'll find things like transmission, IOR, and Specular, defined as "extensions" to the core system — that's a technical detail and doesn't matter here, you can use them anything listed in the docs.